# Sharepoint list item validation

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have created 2 lists :

1. CarInfo(Custom List)
2. Car Booking(Calendar List)

I created columns like `CarName` and `CarNumber`. When I select `CarName`, `CarNumber`, it automatically comes, but, my requirement is, when I select `CarName` , `StartTime` and `EndTime`. For example:

Suppose `CarName` is Car1 , `StartTime` is 1:00pm and `EndTime` is 2:00Pm. Another user can login and add same car and timings.If another user can give same things, it wont allow those fields.

Here, I need validation for those columns. Can anyone help me.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is to write an ItemAdding Event Handler to the list definition using VS2010.

[ItemAdding Event Handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spitemeventreceiver.itemadding.aspx)

In the event hanlder, you will have to loop through the list checking if there is a matching item already.
You can use this code to get the values of the item that is to about to be added.

```
string jobTitle = properties.AfterProperties["Title"].ToString();
```

To cancel the job if item already exists

```
properties.Cancel = true;
```

Use this link to get an idea...

[Creating SharePoint 2010 Event Receivers in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg252010.aspx)